# Keep footer at bottom of body but stay in same column

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am sure this is something easy and I am just missing something, but I can't figure this out to save my life.

I have a webpage the is set up in a 4-column grid format (5% 45% 45% 5%) that I would like to make the footer stay at the bottom of the display window, or the bottom of the content, whichever is lower.  I have tried setting the position to absolute and the bottom to 0, which moves the footer to the bottom, but positions it in the first column only, despite the grid-area being set to the second and third column.

What do I need to do to keep the footer at the bottom, but stay in the columns I have assigned it to?  And no, I don't want a static or sticky footer.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>TITLE</title>
    </head>
         <body>
                <div class="grid">
                    <header>HEADER</header>
                    <nav>NAV</nav>
                    <div class="content1">
                        <h2>HEADLINE1</h2>
                        <p>CONTENT1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content2">
                        <h2>HEADLINE2</h2>
                        <p>CONTENT2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content3">
                        <h2>HEADLINE3</h2>
                        <p>CONTENT3</p>
                    </div>
                    <footer>FOOTER</footer>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
```

CSS:

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
}
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 5% 45% 45% 5%;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
". header header ."  
". content1 content2 ."
". content1 content2 ."
". content3 content3 ."
". footer footer .";
    grid-column-gap: 1em;
    grid-row-gap: .75em;
}
footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
p {
    text-align: justify;
    color: black;
}
.content1 {
    grid-area: content1;
}
.content2 {
    grid-area: content2;
}
.content3 {
    grid-area: content3;
}
.header {
    grid-area: header;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Firstly add your code which you have done...

Comment: show us what you have tried. We cannot do everything for you

Comment: by positioning the footer the way I am it puts the footer inside the first column only when it is supposed to be in the 2nd & 3rd.

Comment: Maybe tidy your HTML first so you don't have 2 bodies, heads etc... CSS may not render correctly on broken pages

Answer (score 0):

First off you really should clean up your code to make sure it's valid and indented correctly, it will make it much easier to spot mistakes. As a side note, you also didn't have `<header>` anywhere in your code.

Secondly, you were missing `display: grid;` inside of your `.grid` styles which will prevent it from working at all.

Once all of that was cleaned up I removed `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;` from your `footer` styles and it seems to work just fine.

Here's my sample of it working: https://codepen.io/CWSites/pen/jdVeNX

Comment: Yes, but that won't keep the footer at the bottom of the display window or content depending on which one is lower.  That is what I am trying to accomplish.